# Changing backgroundColor depending on the state value

Tags: expo, react-native, state, react-native-ios

I am learning how to use React components on React Native and I am now starting the Handling Events. I created a handler that turns a text component to `ON` or `OFF` whenever the user presses the button. I managed to change the color of the button whenever the boolean value of the `state` changes but I haven't managed to do it with the `backgroundColor`of the screen. I tried to create a function `{color}` to render the color depending on the `isToggleOn` but my attempt was unsuccessful.

I think I have to pass a `props` to it but I don't know how to apply it in this case. Could you give me a hand?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: true };

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    //I tried to render the `color` by creating a function
    const { color } = this.state.isToggleOn ? 'red' : 'blue';

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: color,
        }}>
        <Text>{this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</Text>
        <Button
          color={this.state.isToggleOn ? 'red' : 'blue'}
          title={this.state.isToggleOn ? 'TURN OFF' : 'TURN ON'}
          onPress={this.handleClick}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: just delete the brackets that you put on color
instead of doing ```const {color}``` just do ```const color```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
    
        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
    
      handleClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
          // missing this here
          isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn
        }));
      }

    render() {

        // use variable 
        const color = this.state.isToggleOn ? 'red' : 'blue';

        return(
            <View 
                style={{
                    flex:1, 
                    alignItems:'center', 
                    justifyContent:'center',
                    backgroundColor:color}}>
                <Text>
                    {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                </Text>
                <Button color={this.state.isToggleOn ? 'red' : 'blue'} title={this.state.isToggleOn ? 'TURN OFF' : 'TURN ON'} onPress={this.handleClick}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir thank you for answering my question, it worked! But I want to know, what is the difference between using it with or without the curly braces? I know that it is a variable without the braces, but what does it mean when I use it with them?

Comment: `const { name, email } = user` Those braces are generally used if the right hand side of the equality operator is an `object`. In that above example, what it means is `I'm using name and email` properties from a user object. For more details, [you can check this out](https://medium.com/podiihq/destructuring-objects-in-javascript-4de5a3b0e4cb)

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you could use a conditional style on `View` component like this:

```
<View style={this.state.isToggleOn ? styles.bg_red : styles.bg_blue}>
```

Then in your styles:

```
...
bg_blue: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  bg_red: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
  ...
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sun-sbbio?file=/src/App.js) your code modified.